# Issues Parsing JSON Array with Node JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, express

New to Node JS and Express and have the current requiring to build a small proof of concept API in Node.

Currently experiencing issues due to lack of knowledge on how best to parsing JSON arrays to retrieve the required data to select appropriate message by “ sender_id”.

I have been able to make it work with non-array data but cannot get it to work with data in the array.

Current code that works with non-arrays is as follows. Any pointers on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

**JSON**

```
   {
    "data_type": "edijson",
    "payload": {
      "invoices": [{"invoice_6582":
    {
     "sender_id": 5060043358032,
     "buyer_id" : 5055185400478,
     "message_ref": 135353677,
     "document_type": "Commercial",
     "document_name": "MRCHI",
     "document_no": 6582,
     "state": "partial",
     "total_amount": 1008.00,
     "paid_at": "null",
     "invoice_date": "2012-01-30T00:00:00",
     "tax_date": "2012-01-30T00:00:00",
     "amount_due": 1008.00,
     "invoice_no": "6582",
     "order_no": 9899073,
     "supplier_no": "5060043358032",
     "delivery_party" : 5010251999898,
     "vat_reg": 793728185,
   "charges": [
        {
           "created_at": "20120130",
           "item_id": 5010251685524,
           "item_qty": 140,
           "unit_price": 7.20,
           "vat_type": "VAT",
           "vat_rate": 20.00,
           "currency_id" : "GBP",
           "total_amont": 1008.00,
           "type": "Charge"
         }],
   "totals": [
        {
            "invoice_amount": 1008.00,
            "total_amount": 1008.00,
            "tax_amount": 201.60,
            "taxable_amount": 1008.00,
            "allowances": 0.00
         }

        ]
      }
   }
,
{"invoice_6788":
    {
     "sender_id": 5060043358032,
     "buyer_id" : 5055185400478,
     "message_ref": 10636000100020,
     "document_type": "Commercial",
     "document_name": "MRCHI",
     "document_no": 6582,
     "state": "partial",
     "total_amount": 1008.00,
     "paid_at": "null",
     "invoice_date": "2012-01-30T00:00:00",
     "tax_date": "2012-01-30T00:00:00",
     "amount_due": 1008.00,
     "invoice_no": "6788",
     "order_no": 9899073,
     "supplier_no": "5060043358032",
     "delivery_party" : 5010251999898,
     "vat_reg": 793728185,
   "charges": [
        {
           "created_at": "20120130",
           "item_id": 5010251685524,
           "item_qty": 140,
           "unit_price": 7.20,
           "vat_type": "VAT",
           "vat_rate": 20.00,
           "currency_id" : "GBP",
           "total_amont": 1008.00,
           "type": "Charge"
         }],
   "totals": [
        {
            "invoice_amount": 1008.00,
            "total_amount": 1008.00,
            "tax_amount": 201.60,
            "taxable_amount": 1008.00,
            "allowances": 0.00
         }

        ]
      }
   }
,
{"invoice_7786":
    {
     "sender_id": 5060043358032,
     "buyer_id" : 5055185400478,
     "message_ref": 10636000100020,
     "document_type": "Commercial",
     "document_name": "MRCHI",
     "document_no": 6582,
     "state": "partial",
     "total_amount": 1008.00,
     "paid_at": "null",
     "invoice_date": "2012-01-30T00:00:00",
     "tax_date": "2012-01-30T00:00:00",
     "amount_due": 1008.00,
     "invoice_no": "7786",
     "order_no": 9899073,
     "supplier_no": "5060043358032",
     "delivery_party" : 5010251999898,
     "vat_reg": 793728185,
   "charges": [
        {
           "created_at": "20120130",
           "item_id": 5010251685524,
           "item_qty": 140,
           "unit_price": 7.20,
           "vat_type": "VAT",
           "vat_rate": 20.00,
           "currency_id" : "GBP",
           "total_amont": 1008.00,
           "type": "Charge"
         }],
   "totals": [
        {
            "invoice_amount": 1008.00,
            "total_amount": 1008.00,
            "tax_amount": 201.60,
            "taxable_amount": 1008.00,
            "allowances": 0.00
         }

        ]
      }
   }
,
{"invoice_4567":
    {
     "sender_id": 5060043358032,
     "buyer_id" : 5055185400478,
     "message_ref": 10636000100020,
     "document_type": "Commercial",
     "document_name": "MRCHI",
     "document_no": 6582,
     "state": "partial",
     "total_amount": 1008.00,
     "paid_at": "null",
     "invoice_date": "2012-01-30T00:00:00",
     "tax_date": "2012-01-30T00:00:00",
     "amount_due": 1008.00,
     "invoice_no": "4567",
     "order_no": 9899073,
     "supplier_no": "5060043358032",
     "delivery_party" : 5010251999898,
     "vat_reg": 793728185,
   "charges": [
        {
           "created_at": "20120130",
           "item_id": 5010251685524,
           "item_qty": 140,
           "unit_price": 7.20,
           "vat_type": "VAT",
           "vat_rate": 20.00,
           "currency_id" : "GBP",
           "total_amont": 1008.00,
           "type": "Charge"
         }],
   "totals": [
        {
            "invoice_amount": 1008.00,
            "total_amount": 1008.00,
            "tax_amount": 201.60,
            "taxable_amount": 1008.00,
            "allowances": 0.00
         }

        ]
      }
   }
] 
}
}
```

**Node**

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var fs = require("fs");

    app.get('/v1/invoice/:sender_id', function (req, res) {
    // First read existing invoices.
   fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "Invoice.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      data = JSON.parse( data );
      var invoice = data["invoice_" + req.params.sender_id]
      console.log( invoice );
      res.end( JSON.stringify(invoice));
      });
    })

   var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   })
```

Comment: It might be more beneficial if you can post the json data that you are struggling with to make it clearer to anyone trying to help out. Otherwise have you tried looping through the array and searching for the data?

Comment: Hi Stuart,Full Json added to post

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an array, you can loop through it.

```
data.payload.invoices.forEach(function(invoice){
    if (invoice.invoice_no === req.params.id) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Abhyudit, thanks for the response but where would this code be placed in my example?

Comment: after `data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Thanks Abhyudit, running but getting a node response of 'cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined' ?

Comment: That's because data doesn't have any key called "invoices". It should be data.payload.invoices

Comment: By the way, please try console.log() and see what keys are actually there. This code is just an example, you can have different keys. But the principal remains the same. You can access any property of an object by doing `object.property` or `object["property"]`